# My div overlaps its container when writing long text on it

Tags: html, css

I'll try to formulate the question the best way I can, being explicit.

In my website design, I get all the divs (all the parts of the website) of a `width:90%;`, giving a `5%` margin on both sides of the div, making them 'centered'. I'm getting this working by setting the apropiate width and `margin: 0 auto;`.

I'm working on Django's templates, so for the page I'm writing now I'm extending to `'base.html'`. This means I extend the first two divs containing the `header` and the `navigation` menu. There's also a `footer` div on the bottom of the page and, between them, the content I'm adding now.

In this central content div, the structure I want it to have is something like a vertical, `20% width` floating on the left, with two 'content' div's just next to it getting all the space left. Here's an illustration:

[image: Illustration of the design]

**CODE:**

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #content {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: lightyellow;
      height: 80%;
    }
    
    .textoh {
      width: 20%;
      height:75%;
      background-color: darkgrey;
      margin: 5px;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 1em;
    }
    
    .textoup {
      width: 95%;
      height: 60%;
      background-color: lightgreen;
      margin: 5px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      display: inline-block;
    
    }
    
    .textodown {
      width: 95%;
      height: 30%;
      background-color: lightpink;
      margin: 5px;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 6px;
    
    }
    
    .wrap {
      background-color: lightblue;
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 70%;
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="content">
     <div class="textoh">
      <ul>
       <li>INFO</li>
       <li>ABOUT</li>
       <li>LINKS</li>
       <li>OTHERS</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    
    <div class="wrap">
     <div class="textoup">
      <h1>TITLE TITLE TITLE</h1>
    
      <h3>DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION</h3>
     </div>
    
     <div class="textodown">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat.</p>
    
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat.</p>
    
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
     </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

However, I'm getting quite a problem. While writing a more long 'lorem' text, the `.textodown` div, with the `.wrap`, are both getting out of the `#content` div, overlapping the footer.

I'd like to contain it all inside the 'content' div, and if the `.textodown` or `.wrap` are getting a bigger height, make the `#content` div bigger instead of surpassing it.

I'm not english speaker so I don't know if the problem is clear, I'll really appreciate help and if it's not understood, I'd be glad to post some images or whatever is necessary.

Comment: How exactly do you want it to behave with longer content? One solution might be `overflow:auto`. Try to create a working copy so others can fiddle around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `position:absolute` from `.wrap` ( I fixed a bit your `margin`s, but I guess you can manage that)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#content {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: 80%;
}
.textoh {
  width: 20%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  margin: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 1em;
}
.textoup {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 5%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.textodown {
  width: 95%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: lightpink;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.wrap {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.footer {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="textoh">
    <ul>
      <li>INFO</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>LINKS</li>
      <li>OTHERS</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="textoup">
      <h1>TITLE TITLE TITLE</h1>

      <h3>DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="textodown cf">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>

      <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>

      <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">this is a footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That definetly solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code I have removed some heights and adjusted the width.

```css
#content {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
.textoh {
  width: 20%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  margin: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 1em;
}
.textoup {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 5%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.textodown {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: lightpink;
  margin: 2% 5% 5% 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.wrap {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.footer {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="textoh">
    <ul>
      <li>INFO</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>LINKS</li>
      <li>OTHERS</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="textoup">
      <h1>TITLE TITLE TITLE</h1>

      <h3>DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="textodown cf">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>

      <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>

      <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">this is a footer</div>
</div>
```